# How to get SOAP headers

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, cxf

Here is the request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soap="http://soap.ws.server.wst.fit.cvut.cz/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <userId>someId</userId>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
    ...
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and I want to get that `userId`.

I tried this

```
private List<Header> getHeaders() {
    MessageContext messageContext = context.getMessageContext();
    if (messageContext == null || !(messageContext instanceof WrappedMessageContext)) {
        return null;
    }
    Message message = ((WrappedMessageContext) messageContext).getWrappedMessage();
    return CastUtils.cast((List<?>) message.get(Header.HEADER_LIST));
}

private String getHeader(String name) {
    List<Header> headers = getHeaders();
    if (headers != null) {
        for (Header header : headers) {
            logger.debug(header.getObject());
            // return header by the given name                   
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And it logs `[userId : null]`. How can I get the value and why is `null` there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"[userId : null]" is generally the "toString" printout of a DOM element.   Most likely if you do something like

```
logger.debug(header.getObject().getClass())
```

you will see that it is a DOM Element subclass of somesort.  Thus, something like:

```
logger.debug(((Element)header.getObject()).getTextContent())
```

might print the text node.

Answer (score 7):

```
    import javax.xml.soap.*;

    SOAPPart part = request.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope env = part.getEnvelope();
    SOAPHeader header = env.getHeader();
    if (header == null) {
        // Throw an exception
     }

    NodeList userIdNode = header.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "userId");
    String userId = userIdNode.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
```

Comment: Dunno how efficient and reliable this code snippet is but worked well for me ;)

Comment: I found this answer helpful because it (correctly) shows how to extract things out of the SOAP header.

Comment: `SOAPPart part = request.getSOAPPart();` this part give me error, as it can't identify request.

Comment: How do you obtain the request here?

Answer (score 2):

You can get soap headers without Interceptors and without JAXB.

In your service_impl class add :

```
public class YourFunctionNameImpl implements YourFunctionName{

@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;

private List<Header> getHeaders() {
    MessageContext messageContext = context.getMessageContext();
    if (messageContext == null || !(messageContext instanceof WrappedMessageContext)) {
        return null;
    }

    Message message = ((WrappedMessageContext) messageContext).getWrappedMessage();
    List<Header> headers = CastUtils.cast((List<?>) message.get(Header.HEADER_LIST));
    return headers;
}
```

...

Then in your function you can use:

```
List<Header> headers = getHeaders();
        for(Iterator<Header> i = headers.iterator(); i.hasNext();) { 
            Header h = i.next(); 
            Element n = (Element)h.getObject(); 

            System.out.println("header name="+n.getLocalName()); 
            System.out.println("header content="+n.getTextContent()); 
    }
```

Comment: this method was more convenient for me to access the SOAP headers from service layer.
CXF FAQ:
http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIaddsoapheaderstotherequest/response?

Answer (score 1):

We can get SOAP header in server side by adding following code in CXF interceptor.

Create a class like

public class ServerCustomHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;

public ServerCustomHeaderInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.INVOKE);

}

@Override
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault,JAXBException {
    System.out.println("ServerCustomHeaderInterceptor  handleMessage");
    JAXBContext jc=null;
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller=null;
    try {
    jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.example.hello_ws");
    unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }


    List<Header> list = message.getHeaders();
    for (Header header : list) {
            ElementNSImpl el = (ElementNSImpl) header.getObject();
        ParentNode pn= (ParentNode) el.getFirstChild();
        //Node n1= (Node) pn;
        //Node n1= (Node) el.getFirstChild();

        CustomHeader customHeader=(CustomHeader)  unmarshaller.unmarshal(el.getFirstChild());


    }

}
```

After this we need to inject this as a interceptor like

```
 <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
    <bean class="org.example.hellows.soap12.ServerCustomHeaderInterceptor" />
   </jaxws:inInterceptors>
```

in your server context xml.

We may need to change few lines as per your requirements. Basic flow will work like this.

Answer (score 0):

Having a `MessageContext` messageContext, you can use this code:

```
HeaderList hl = (HeaderList) messageContext.get(JAXWSProperties.INBOUND_HEADER_LIST_PROPERTY);
```

which gives you access to all SOAP headers.

Comment: As I see it, `HeaderList` and `JAXWSProperties` are classes in `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.*` package. I really don't want to use this...

Comment: [MessageContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/MessageContext.html) is part of the regular java packages, now