# How to convert apache.cfx.header object to OMElement

Tags: java, apache-axis, axiom

I got the Header type object. Now I want to get its child elements. The Soap header contains a binary security tag. I can not get its content. The list contains these tags:

```
List<Header>ls=getHeader();
OMElement element=(OMElement)element;
```

but can I cast Like that?

Comment: I have already read List of Header type objects.Header class contains method getObject.then cast object to Element type object.Then you can traverse like DOM.

Comment: we can not cast like that

Comment: Have you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284486/how-to-get-soap-headers

Comment: Thanx.I have already get the answer.Yah it also related with above link post.

Comment: Great. Since you have found the answer, accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This helps me to read the SOAP header.](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://gist.github.com/hasuniea/492593d54c5d60b409be.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

```
private List<Header> getHeaders() {

     MessageContext messageContext = context.getMessageContext();
     if (messageContext == null || !(messageContext instanceof WrappedMessageContext)) {
        return null;
     }      

     Message message = ((WrappedMessageContext) messageContext).getWrappedMessage();
     List<Header> headers = CastUtils.cast((List<?>) message.get(Header.HEADER_LIST));

     return headers;
}
```