# How to write WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have created a Dynamic Web Project using Eclipse IDE, and the exposed web service method is given below, ie.CallPaySecure().

I want to know how to create a soap service which will accept soap-header as below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <RequestorCredentials xmlns="https://paysecure/merchant.soap.header/">
      <Version>string</Version>
      <UserCredentials>
        <UserID>string</UserID>
        <Password>string</Password>
      </UserCredentials>
    </RequestorCredentials>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CallPaySecure xmlns="https://paysecure/merchant.soap/">
      <strCommand>string</strCommand>
      <strXML>string</strXML>
    </CallPaySecure>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have written the following code in java

`@WebMethod`

`@WebResult(name="CallPaySecureResult")`

```js
public String CallPaySecure(
   @WebParam(name="strCommand")String strCmd,
   @WebParam(name="strXML") String strXML ){
  }
```

But this code can only get value from the following tags.

```html
<strCommand>string</strCommand>      
<strXML>string</strXML>
```

1.My WSDL is auto generated by the Glassfish server v4, how can I modify the WSDL or what java code should I use to accept the above mentioned XML SOAP request?

2.How to define the `<soap:Header>` in the WSDL, so that I can access the values that comes in `<Version>`,`<UserID>` and `<Password>` in my web service CallPaySecure()?

I am using SOAP for the first time.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I dont know how to do second part. Here are links that might help. [How to get soap headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284486/how-to-get-soap-headers) [Soap Headers](https://metro.java.net/nonav/1.2/guide/SOAP_headers.html)

Answer (score 3):

Generate Java client from WSDL using your IDE. Write your implementation logic in generated Java class file.

Fox example here is how you generate Java client from eclipse

1) Create **Dynamic Web Project** from **File -> New ->Dynamic Web Project**

2) Click on the project and open context menu **New -> Other** and from the window select **Web service client**

[image]

3) Click **Browse** and select WSDL address or local WSDL file
[image]

4) Click Finish. All necessary java files will be generated in Dynamic web project

If you want to generate Java client without any IDE [HERE](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/) is tutorial using **wsimport**

Comment: This is correct, but far too sparse to be a good answer.  Explain how to do it, in at least one IDE.  You should also mention that generating Java from a WSDL is part of the JAX-WS standard (and by extension, the JAXB standard), and in fact can be done without any IDE using the `wsimport` tool that comes with every JDK.

Comment: Thank you @DatoMumladze I have done as you suggested please find the updated question.