# How to get request header (SOAP) from Apache CXF Interceptor

Tags: spring-boot, soap, wsdl, cxf

I'm working on the client side where I have generated classes from wsdl and @Service which calls methods of @WebService generated from the wsdl. My task is to get soap header which is returned when I call method on the server. I have implemented interceptor, marked it as a bean in cxf client configuration. How can I now get the header?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284486/how-to-get-soap-headers

Comment: The problem si that web service context is always null, even if I marked it as resource.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have written `SoapActionInInterceptor` in `READ` phase. Then when you override `handleMessage` method you will have `SoapMessage` as its parameter and you can take the Soap Header also from it. Check [Apache CXF Guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html)  for more reference

Comment: Yes I did wrote it in READ phase.  The problem is how to invoke handleMessage, I tried with  web service context but it is null even if I marked it as a resource.

Comment: If I get your question correctly. I think you need to put your interceptors in chain. since it is not registered. whereever you are taking client factory you need to add this interceptor there.